# How can I redirect a subdomain with special characters in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm very new to editing .htaccess

For a couple of subdomains I'm trying to redirect them to the respective pages of the new website layout.

I know the implementation to do this in .htaccess isn't ideal.

Since I don't believe a redirect will work for a subdomain (if possible, with what syntax?), I tried to do it with rewriting.

I have this part working fine to redirect a subdomain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/weblog/$1 [NC,QSA]
```

Somehow this doesn't seem to redirect correctly:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^long-subdomain-for-some-reason.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/pretty-long-directory/$1 [NC,QSA]
```

I think the dashes in either of the two may be throwing it off, but I can't identify how to fix this.

Comment: The dashes shouldn't be a problem. What `doesn't seem to redirect correctly` means, what exactly happens?

Comment: The subdomains are directing to the root: example.com and with the above code, going to blog.example.com redirects to http://example.com/weblog/ whereas going to long-subdomain-for-some-reason.example.com stays at the root as if the code wasn't there at all. 

There are no spelling mistakes in the domain or folder name of the second example.

I am certain the browser cache has already cleared, since I use a specific test redirect that I redirect to a different file each time I changed to be certain.

If the dashes shouldn't be a problem I'm truly stumped.

Comment: What happens if you manually enter `http://example.com/pretty-long-directory/` in address bar?

Comment: I arrive at http://example.com/pretty-long-directory/ which is different from http://example.com

Comment: How many characters exactly is `long-subdomain-for-some-reason` long?

Comment: including http, dashes and slashes , it's 45. The subdomain part itself is 26

Comment: Strange. Can you add R=301 flag also (so have `[NC,QSA,R=301]`) and check the output from `curl -v long-subdomain-for-some-reason.example.com`, look for `Location:` header

Comment: Also, (I am not native English speaker so it seemed the same :), make sure you use [hyphen, not dash](http://www.dashhyphen.com/)

Comment: That's already informative regarding hyphen and dash, thank you! I did mean hyphen. I also doublechecked, but I'm certain the same character is being used and I don't expect .htaccess to read it differently.Thank you for taking an interest so far. I will report what the [r=301] and curl -v will result

Comment: Contrary to the other subdomain that is redirecting, it does not have a location header.

Comment: There should be request Host: header visible, what does it say?

Comment: Host: long-subdomain-for-some-reason.example.com

Comment: What about the IP address in `Connected to` line, is it the same as when you request blog.example.com?

Comment: Do you have access to apache .conf files?

Comment: I probably could get access, though only for reading, I suspect.

Comment: Well, from what I can figure out so far, I suspect that request never hits the RewriteRule because it is being processed by another apache VirtualHost or by some directive in .conf which navigates away from the DocumentRoot folder where .htacccess resides. One more way to verify this is to place dummy.html with some content in the same root folder where .htaccess is and see if `http://long-subdomain-for-some-reason.example.com/dummy.html` opens correctly

Comment: I'm trying it with test.html so: http://long-subdomain-for-some-reason.example.com/test.html and this opens correctly.

I will see if I can get access to and find anything in the .conf

Comment: I just tested on my box, exactly copied as above, worked like charm (Apache/2.2.15). So, look for `AllowOverride None` in the config.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: Not yet, thank you for checking in.

I did not get access to the config.

Since the exact code worked for you, I'm going to test it out on a friend's server this week. I'll update you on the results. In any case, you've been a tremendous help.